# Is it possible to bridge Ethernet and WiFi on IP level for the same network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, ip, routing

I'd like to expose a virtual machine to a WiFi network. I'd like to have it in the same network. Would setting a route table and ip forwarding works or is it waste of time and I should set up two networks and update the WiFi router routing tables (if that's possible)?

**EDIT** [Note that L2 bridge with WiFi is not possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/152363/bridging-wlan0-to-eth0)

Comment: When I want a VirtualBox VM Machine to be bridged with my network, I set it as Bridge instead of NAT. That way, both the host and the guest can see each other's IPs, the host and other nodes on the network can see the guest's IP and the guest can also see their IPs.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft I know about it but that's not possible directly due to WiFi limitations (see update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now though I'd like to figure out a way to bridge mDNS as well (possibly as separate question). This follows [this guide](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/).

1. Set up tap device (in my case it was done by virsh). Don't assign it any host address
2. Set the ip forwarding and arp proxy
3. Add route for this one specific ip only OR run a separate DHCP server for tap and add route for this subnetwork.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to put a virtual machine directly on a Wifi network... is to put it directly on a Wifi network!

Get a [USB Wifi adapter](http://www.j5create.com/our-products/wifi-adapters.html), and "connect" it to your virtual guest.  Then your virtual guest can use the USB Wifi adapter directly and independently of the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I use VMWare most often, and I just set the guest OS's network card to be bridged to the Host network.  The Guest doesn't know or care about the hardware layer in this case; VMWare handles the networking.

Based on a comment above, it's going to be similar in other VM products.

Comment: [Except that it is not possible to bridge with WiFi cards.](https://serverfault.com/questions/152363/bridging-wlan0-to-eth0)